# Unknown field type: 64 when trying to open DBF database

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbf

I am trying to open a dbf file using the **dbf** library to send read data to the production application API.

Unfortunately, when I try to open a dbf file containing orders that I need to send to the API I get the following error:

```
File "C:\...\IntegrationEngine.py", line 686, in za00za
    table = dbf.Table(path, codepage='cp852', ignore_memos=True).open()
File "C:\...\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 5526, in __init__
    self._initialize_fields()
File "C:\...\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 6427, in _initialize_fields
    raise BadDataError("Unknown field type: %s" % type)
dbf.BadDataError: Unknown field type: 64
```

As I mentioned earlier, I use the dbf library.

`import dbf`

I am trying to open a dbf database using this line:

`table = dbf.Table(path, codepage='cp852', ignore_memos=True).open()`

I have no idea how to deal with such an error. The file I am trying to open is the za00za*.dbf file used by Trawers ERP application (by Tres, here is the demo: https://tres.pl/demo).

**EDIT:**

I tried to add some "debug prints" to copy of dbf library so I added

```
print("Name: %s, Type: %s" % (name, type))
```

few lines above error message (6427 line in **init**.py of dbf lib) and I find out, which column(s) are "broken":

```
(a lot of other columns...)
Name: VJEDPRZE, Type: 78
Name: VSYMBOLB, Type: 67
Name: VNRTAB, Type: 67
Name: VRODZKUR, Type: 78
Name: ODMKASTN, Type: 67
Name: CLREASON, Type: 67
Name: CLSYMOP, Type: 67
Name: CLDATE, Type: 64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\IE_TEST.py", line 5, in <module>
    table = dbf.Table(path, codepage='cp852', ignore_memos=True).open()
  File "C:\...\dbf\__init__.py", line 5526, in __init__
    self._initialize_fields()
  File "C:\...\dbf\__init__.py", line 6428, in _initialize_fields
    raise BadDataError("Unknown field type: %s" % type)
dbf.BadDataError: Unknown field type: 64
```

Is there any way to skip this column or something like that?

Comment: What type of database file is it?  `dbf` handles 3, clipper, and vfp up to 6.  `64` is the `@` sign, which isn't a format in any of the supported versions.

Comment: This database type should be clipper. How can I check it for this specified database file? A lot of other dbf files from same application works fine, this one doesnt.

Comment: @EthanFurman can you please check my edit on this post? Maybe it will help in something

Comment: Looks like the `'@'` column is a time stamp.  What do you get with `dbf.table_type(path)` ?

Comment: (131, 'dBase III Plus w/memos')

Comment: Send me an email, and I'll send you a test copy with `@` support -- make sure and have a backup of your dbf file in case something gets messed up!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229168/discussion-between-mateoskyline-and-ethan-furman).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the column type Timestamp (@) is not currently supported.  Thanks to the OP's help, though, it will be in the next release.